# Source code for android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMV() method

Tags: java, android, matrix, opengl-es

I'm looking for the source code for `android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMV()` method. Going through the source code of android opengl Matrix class ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/opengl/java/android/opengl/Matrix.java)), I can see that multiplyMV is a native method. So, it would seem that the implementation must be written in some other language (maybe C or C++ ??). I have researched but have not found where could I find the implementation code. Could someone guide me on how to find the source code.

Comment: You can find it under `frameworks/base/core/jni/android/opengl/util.cpp`: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/jni/android/opengl/util.cpp;l=595;drc=b821c815077b1c435c268cc07ede3ec9ff2baeca;bpv=0;bpt=1